# Why snapshot for google maps is generated only on click event end?

Tags: android, google-maps

I use snapshot to get image of current google maps view on the screen. The snapshot is needed, when user presses "share" on action bar.
After snapshot is created I need to use this file for other function but snapshot is always generated after all actions are finished. Is there any way to wait for snapshot or other workaround? (it is obviously not timing issue, snapshot is always generated at end no matter how much and long code is between)

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.share:
            GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback callback = new GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback() {
                Bitmap bitmap;
                @Override
                public void onSnapshotReady(Bitmap snapshot) {
                    bitmap = snapshot;
                    try {
                        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("/mnt/sdcard/Download/map.png");
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                           e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };
            mMap.snapshot(callback);

            functionThatUsesSnapshot();
           return true; //snapshot present only here

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to put your code in the onSnapshotReadyCallback, that's where the picture is ready, so after your bitmap.compress function.